# Simplifying the output to Reduce

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a system of inequalities in Mathematica using `Reduce`:

```
u1 = -((b + β + a1)/((b + β) rμ));
u2 = -((μ a2)/((1 + b μ + β μ) rμ)); Reduce[
 Abs[1 + rμ u1] > Abs[rμ u2] && 
  b > 0 && β > 0 && μ > 0 && 0 < rμ <= 1 && 
  Abs[u1] >= 1 && a1 > 0, {a1, a2}, Reals]
```

with the output:

```
β > 0 && b > 0 && 0 < rμ <= 1 && μ > 0 && 
 a1 > 0 && (-a1 - a1 b μ - a1 β μ)/(
  b μ + β μ) < a2 < (
  a1 + a1 b μ + a1 β μ)/(b μ + β μ)
```

(Also see the screenshot)
[image]

Note that the simplest way of expressing `a2` to a human perhaps would be:

```
-a1 (1 + 1/((b + β) μ)) < a2 < 
 a1 (1 + 1/((b + β) μ))
```

i.e.,
[image]

Is there a systematic way to express the output to `Reduce` in a more simplified format as shown above? Any tips/suggestions will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

u1 = -((b + β + a1)/((b + β) rμ));
u2 = -((μ a2)/((1 + b μ + β μ) rμ));

sol = Reduce[
  Abs[1 + rμ u1] > Abs[rμ u2] && 
   b > 0 && β > 0 && μ > 0 && 0 < rμ <= 1 && 
   Abs[u1] >= 1 && a1 > 0, {a1, a2}, Reals]

(* β > 0 && b > 0 && 0 < rμ <= 1 && μ > 0 && 
 a1 > 0 && (-a1 - a1 b μ - a1 β μ)/(
  b μ + β μ) < a2 < (
  a1 + a1 b μ + a1 β μ)/(b μ + β μ) *)

Collect[FullSimplify /@ sol[[-1]], a1]

(* a1 (-1 - 1/((b + β) μ)) < a2 < 
 a1 (1 + 1/((b + β) μ)) *)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Bob!

Comment: @Bob Hanlon Bob, what do you do to make the Greek letters, rather than \[Beta] and alike in the StackExchange?

Comment: I used this [`link`](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1044/9362) for additional buttons for the MSE editor. I use Chrome browser.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.
This is your system:

```
u1 = -((b + \[Beta] + a1)/((b + \[Beta]) r\[Mu]));
u2 = -((\[Mu] a2)/((1 + b \[Mu] + \[Beta] \[Mu]) r\[Mu])); 

sys1 = 
 Reduce[Abs[1 + r\[Mu] u1] > Abs[r\[Mu] u2] && 
   b > 0 && \[Beta] > 0 && \[Mu] > 0 && 0 < r\[Mu] <= 1 && 
   Abs[u1] >= 1 && a1 > 0, {a1, a2}, Reals];
```

Step1:

```
sys2 = MapAt[Apart[Simplify[#]] &, sys1, {6}]

(*  \[Beta] > 0 && b > 0 && 0 < r\[Mu] <= 1 && \[Mu] > 0 && 
 a1 > 0 && -a1 - a1/((b + \[Beta]) \[Mu]) < a2 < 
  a1 + a1/((b + \[Beta]) \[Mu])   *)
```

Step 2:

```
sys3 = sys2 /. 
  a_/((b + \[Beta]) \[Mu]) -> a*Hold[1/((b + \[Beta]) \[Mu])]

(*  \[Beta] > 0 && b > 0 && 0 < r\[Mu] <= 1 && \[Mu] > 0 && 
 a1 > 0 && -a1 - a1 Hold[1/((b + \[Beta]) \[Mu])] < a2 < 
  a1 + a1 Hold[1/((b + \[Beta]) \[Mu])]  *)
```

Step 3:

```
MapAt[Factor, sys3, {{6, 1}, {6, 5}}] // ReleaseHold

(*  \[Beta] > 0 && b > 0 && 0 < r\[Mu] <= 1 && \[Mu] > 0 && 
 a1 > 0 && -a1 (1 + 1/((b + \[Beta]) \[Mu])) < a2 < 
  a1 (1 + 1/((b + \[Beta]) \[Mu]))   *)
```

[image]

Done. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks so much, Alexei!

Answer (score 1):

If `result` is the result of your `Reduce[..]`, then try this:

```
Map[FullSimplify, result, {2}]
```

[image]

I'm not sure why you want to get rid of some of the conditions. It could be done by deleting the inequalities that do not contain `{a1, a2}` or just `a2`:

```
DeleteCases[%, i_ /; FreeQ[i, a1 | a2]] (* or just FreeQ[i, a2] *)
```

[image]

---

*Notes:*
The argument `{a1, a2}` to `Reduce` in the OP means that each solution will have a form in an order with `a1` and `a2` coming last:

```
conditions && Inequality[..., a1,...] && Inequality[..., a2,...]
```

If there are multiple solutions, it will have a form like `sol1 || sol2 || ...`, but `And` and `Or` will be nested in a way so that the repetition of conditions will be somewhat minimized.  The irregular nesting makes the form somewhat difficult to postprocess programmatically.  Usually `LogicalExpand[result]` yields a matrix-like structure:

```
Or[
 And[cond1, i11, i12,...],
 And[cond2, i21, i22,...],
 ...
 ]
```

However, it often happens that some of the solutions can be combined to a simpler form.  For instance, conditions over circle are often split into semicircles and sometimes into open semicircles and their endpoints (4 pieces).  This is an artifact of the algorithm and sometimes not strictly necessary.  It can be hard to combine them, except by hand.

*P.S.*
If this particular problem is the only such problem you face, then copying the code typed in the OP is the easiest solution, `-a1 (1 + 1/((b + β) μ)) < a2 < a1 (1 + 1/((b + β) μ))`.  I can see no reason for doing a lot of work just to get Mathematica to give a human-optimal solution when typing it out is so easy, especially when it's programmed to produce computation-oriented solutions.

*P.P.S*
More work, simpler result:

```
Map[FullSimplify[#, 
   TransformationFunctions ->
    {Automatic, Factor, -Simplify[-#] &}] &,
 result, {2}]
```

[image]